# Something deleted java.exe, how to find what it was?

Tags: windows-7, windows, java, virus

On Windows 7 Pro SP1, the files java.exe, javaw.exe and so on are being automatically deleted by something, how can I find out what it is?

When I uninstall and re-install java I see these files being added to the java bin directory during installation (95 files in bin dir).  When the install finishes these files just disappear - they have been deleted by something.  What is it?

Alternatively if I install the JDK, then java.exe, javaw.exe etc are still in the jdk/bin folder after install finishes.  But if I go to the cmd prompt and type /jdk/bin/java then the files disappear from the jdk folder too.  Why?

Comment: I assume this is a personal computer?

Comment: Does [OpenJDK](https://github.com/alexkasko/openjdk-unofficial-builds) install fine? Also, if you open `java.exe` in windows explorer, does it get deleted then too? What if you rename `java.exe` to `blah.exe` then execute it?

Comment: Yes its on my laptop, minecraft stopped working and I tracked it down to the java.exe file being deleted any time it is run

Answer (score 6):

There's a tool approved by Microsoft called [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) that can show file operations, including read, modify, and delete. It will display the process that executed the command, as well as other identifying information.

Since you can easily reproduce your issue, you can "record" what the computer does while you do those steps, and then filter the captured events based on certain criteria, in your case you'd be looking for "java.exe" as the manipulated file.

Comment: Ok thanks I will try that and see if it says anything useful