# Application files being deleted repatedly - how to find what it did?

Tags: windows-10, process, monitoring

A folder containing executable files for an application under ProgramData on Windows 10 is being deleted repeatedly on my laptop, only empty app folder remains. I have looked into this: [Something deleted java.exe, how to find what it was?](https://superuser.com/questions/732332/something-deleted-java-exe-how-to-find-what-it-was)

I need a way to find out what deleted the file, antivirus or system event logs provide no info.

How can I use some tool like ProcessMonitor or something else to catch the delete event of a specific EXE file and see which process did it?

---

Based on @John comment I have enabled auditing on the EXE file:

[image: Audit]

Comment: Enable File Auditing. Only works going forward. .....  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder

Comment: @John for Select a principal should be `Everyone` ...?

Comment: On your own machine you can use Everyone.

Comment: @John Ok, the file got deleted and looking for events in security log I cannot see any thing...?

Comment: If you enabled auditing after the deletion, there probably is not a record.

Comment: @John That auditing just produces no records at all for any deletes or anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried the to turn on security auditing for the folder being deleted, but nothing at all was logged. After different attempts I let [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) log file events for the problematic folder overnight.

In the morning I found the folder empty and this in the PM log:

```
20:41:44,7475236,"SRE.exe","14044","SetDispositionInformationEx",
"C:\ProgramData\MyProblematicFolder\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook12.dll",
"SUCCESS","Flags: FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE, FILE_DISPOSITION_POSIX_SEMANTICS, FILE_DISPOSITION_FORCE_IMAGE_SECTION_CHECK"
```

FILE_DISPOSITION_DELETE:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntddk/ns-ntddk-_file_disposition_information_ex

This strange PM log event caused by

```
C:\Program Files\Dell\SupportAssistAgent\SRE\SRE.exe
```

Which belongs to [DELL Support assist agent](https://www.shouldiremoveit.com/dell-supportassistagent-149315-program.aspx).

[image]

They unfortunately added malfunctioning malware removal feature to their software:

[image]

Comment: Now that you've found what's doing it, you might want to "disable all automated scans and optimizations" as written in the Dell forum article [How to stop Support Assistant Clean Files from deleting cookies?](https://www.dell.com/community/en/conversations/supportassist-for-pcs/how-to-stop-support-assistant-clean-files-from-deleting-cookies/647f8b3ff4ccf8a8deb4ca3c)

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Event Viewer.
2. In the console tree, expand Applications and Services Logs >
   Microsoft > Windows > Windows Defender.
3. Double-click on Operational.
4. In the details pane, view the list of individual events to find your
   event.
5. Click the event to see specific details about an event in the lower
   pane, under the General and Details tabs.

If you can find Events there check to find Event ID 1011 or Event ID 1013

Event ID 1011 = Symbolic name: MALWAREPROTECTION_QUARANTINE_DELETE
Event ID 1013 = Symbolic name: MALWAREPROTECTION_MALWARE_HISTORY_DELETE

and of course check inside the event the Path: File path

Comment: I do not use Windows Defender, other antivirus says nothing.

Comment: did you try the solution from: Oran D. Lord with [Processmonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645)?